# Move 2D Point from one Transform Matrix to another, while keeping position on canvas

Tags: javascript, 2d, transform

I have a point at a known position, say (25, 40) on a Canvas, after it the canvas has gone through multiple context transformations (translate, rotate, scale...). But I want to know the location of the pixel, because those numbers are within the transformed context.

```
// I can get the current transform matrix with:
let old_matrix = ctx.getTransform()

// Reset transform to default to undo all the transformations
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

What kind of mathematics do I need to do to be able to find the location of the pixel within a the new matrix? Is there a library to handle the transforming of this point?